# Hiding a component in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a component inside an `<a/>` tag that opens a popup window on click. It's an "add to favourite" link which works on KML files. My KML file has a field named "favourite[boolean]". Now I'd like to hide or show my "add to favourite" link. The KML list is generated with a table:

```
public class CustomTracksAjaxDataTable<T> extends CustomAjaxDataTable<T> {
    public CustomTracksAjaxDataTable(String id, List<IColumn<T>> iColumns,
      ISortableDataProvider<T> tiSortableDataProvider, int rowsPerPage) {
        super(id, iColumns, tiSortableDataProvider, rowsPerPage);
    }

    protected void onEventHandler(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget,
      KMLFile file) {
        setKMLData(file); // it just update map, dont care about it
        add(new FavouriteStarIconState(file.isSaved()));
    }
}
```

I tried to add a behavior thus:

```
public class FavouriteStarIconState extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {
    private boolean isFavourite;

    public FavouriteStarIconState(boolean isFavourite) {
        super();
        this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
    }

    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (isFavourite) {
            target.appendJavascript("jQuery('.map_container_star').css(
              {'display' : 'none' });");
        } else {
            target.appendJavascript("jQuery('.map_container_star').css(
              {'display' : 'block' });");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderOnLoadJavascript(getCallbackScript().toString());
    }
}
```

The part of the HTML containing the component:

```
<div id="map_container">
    <a wicket:id="favourite_star" class="map_container_star"></a>
</div>
```

This isn't working. I got the same result with `component.setVisible(false)`. How can I get hiding to work?

Comment: Have you looked at the `isVisible()` method of `Component`? You can override it and Wicket will take care of the rest, you just need to add the component to the `AjaxRequestTarget`. There are limitations to this solution but usually it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it finds out that I make a terrible mistake and put javascript appending in wrong place. AJAX request was not rendered. The proper class was CustomAjaxDataTable being extended by my class CustomTracksAjaxDataTable. I just add

```
new AjaxEventBehavior( "onclick" )
```

and override

```
protected void onEvent( AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget )
```

and it works great now

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS class like this

```
  .hiddenClass
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

then with *AttributeModifier* you add the class to the element

```
component.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "hiddenClass"));
```

or add the style directly to the *style* attribute

```
component.add(new AttributeModifier("style", "visibility:hidden;"));
```

Comment: I get 'The constructor AttributeModifier(String, String) is undefined'. Maybe I'm using a different version of Wicket.

Comment: could be, the answere is 4 years old